# Laravel migration without specifying the column type

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to create a migration that changes an existing column but does not specify the column type?

For example, if you want to add a comment to a column, you can do this:

```php
$table->string('column_name')->comment('This is the comment')->change();
```

However, I want to add a comment to the `updated_at` timestamp column, which seems impossible.

```php
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->comment('This is the comment')->change();
```

fails due to Doctrine not supporting `timestamp` as a type. How else can I target the `updated_at` column to add a comment?

I'm hoping for something like:

```php
$table->column('updated_at')->comment('This is the comment')->change();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#modifying-columns), only following column types can be changed :

`Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.`

You can use raw statement inside migration :

```
\DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at ` timestamp NULL COMMENT 'This is the comment'")
```

Comment: Thanks! The raw SQL statement is a perfectly usable workaround that hadn't occurred to me. It does seem odd to have such a seemingly-arbitrary limitation on which column types can be changed, especially when you're talking about something that seems trivial like adding a comment.